# traitのConstにconst genericsを引き渡すことは可能か?

Tags: rust

## 実行環境

- nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu

  - rust version 1.78.0-nightly (3b1717c05 2024-03-10)

## 質問内容

お世話様です。

概略以下のようなコードを考えたとき、コンパイルエラーになってしまいました。

```rs
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

trait ArrayReturn {
    const SIZE: usize;

    fn get_array(&self) -> Box<[usize; Self::SIZE]>;
}

fn f<const N: usize, T: ArrayReturn<SIZE = N>>() {}

fn main() {}
```

エラーメッセージは以下の通りです

```
error[E0573]: expected type, found const parameter `N`
 --> playground\src\main.rs:9:44
  |
9 | fn f<const N: usize, T: ArrayReturn<SIZE = N>>() {}
  |                      -                     ^ help: a type parameter with a similar name exists: `T`
  |                      |
  |                      similarly named type parameter `T` defined here
```

実務上は可変長引数であるVecを返せばWorkaroundは可能なのですが、出来れば正格性を期すために静的に配列のサイズを決定しておきたいというモチベーションがあります。

尚、`#![feature(associated_const_equality)]`を付与した上でNでは無く`42usize`等の整数リテラルを埋め込んだ場合は問題なくコンパイル可能なのですが、  今回の要求を残念ながら満たすことが出来ませんでした。

この件に関して、回避策含めまして何か知見をお持ちの方は何卒ご教授いただきますようよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

定数パラメタとして受け取ったものを使うときは波括弧で囲まなければならないという構文上の制限があるようです。

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]
#![feature(associated_const_equality)]

trait ArrayReturn {
    const SIZE: usize;

    fn get_array(&self) -> Box<[usize; Self::SIZE]>;
}

fn f<const N: usize, T:ArrayReturn<SIZE = {N}>>()
{
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: ご教授ありがとう御座いました。

回答を拝見して、
Const expr扱いなので`{}`で括る必要が出てくるかなと個人的に考えた次第です。